# Using react-router-dom with children

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I am trying to use children, within a route only that with the react-router-dom I can not access this.props.childre so I did it this way:

Index.js:

```
<Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
      <Route path="/bank-account" component={BankAccount}/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

App.js:

```
<Router>
    <div className="uk-offcanvas-content">
        <Header store={this.context.store}/>
        <main className="wt-main">
            <SideBar/>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/historic" component={Historic}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} profile={profile}/>
            <Route exact path="/receivable" component={Receivable}/>
            <Route exact path="/operators" component={Operators}/>
            <Route exact path="/create-operator" component={CreateOperator}/>
       </main>
       <footer>
       </footer>
       <SideBarResponsive/>
   </div>
```

The problem is that when I try to access the internal routes through the browser it appears a blank page, but if I access the link or redirect it works normally

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue for a dashboard container I'm working on. I found that adding the routes I nested in the container's render method to the route config in my index.js fixed the problem.

Your App component renders the nested routes, but when accessed directly (for example if the nested route is bookmarked) the page is blank because the root component doesn't have a Route with an exact match to render (removing the 'exact' prop did not change this in my case).

Leave App.js as is, and add the nested routes to your index.js:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
    <Route path="/bank-account" component={BankAccount}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path="/historic" component={Historic}/>
    <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} profile={profile}/>
    <Route exact path="/receivable" component={Receivable}/>
    <Route exact path="/operators" component={Operators}/>
    <Route exact path="/create-operator" component={CreateOperator}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

The v4 docs do not currently specify this as needed when using the old route config architecture, however the same problem/solution can be replicated by placing the example code (from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) in your app and creating a Route for it in your index.js.